# Create a PDF from gdoc

Tags: grails

Since nearly all Grails plugins come with a PDF as documentation, there seems to be an easy way to create nice looking PDFs from gdoc, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. stupid me. The obvious solution it the right option:

```
grails doc -pdf
```

will create a PDF called `single.pdf`